# parsing SoapObject XML with empty tag

Tags: xml, parsing, soap, envelope

Hi everyone I Parsing Soaobject xml from webservice and then xml tags are not empty there is everything ok, but then they are empty example " `<barcode></barcode>`"  it make string- anyType{}. and shows it in my list!
 :( What i should do to remove from list this word "anyType{}" and it shows nothing or something that i write?
  envelope.implicitTypes= false; ---> this is not working.... still get anyType{}...
here is my code:

**String[] xmlElements={"Id","name","Unit","Cost","description","barcode"};**

```
  SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
      envelope.dotNet=true;
      envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

      androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); 

      ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> Tags = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

      if ( xmlelements==null&& KEY_RAKTINIS==null){
          Object soapObj = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
          soapObj = ((SoapObject) soapObj).getProperty(KEY_PATVIRTINIMAS);
         Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), soapObj.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      }else {
            SoapObject soapObj = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
   soapObj = (SoapObject) soapObj.getProperty(KEY_RAKTINIS);// su situo ieinu i butent customers punkta

      for (int  j = 0; j < soapObj.getPropertyCount(); j++) {
        SoapObject   soapObjMenu = (SoapObject) soapObj.getProperty(j);

    for (int  i = 0; i <1; i++) {
              HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
                    for( i=0; i < xmlelements.length;i++){

           if (soapObjMenu.getProperty(xmlelements[i])!="") { 
               map.put(xmlelements[i], (soapObjMenu.getProperty(xmlelements[i]).toString()));
               Log.v(xmlelements[i], "sitas");}
              }

                    Tags.add(map);
                                }}
```

`<Items>`

`<Item>`

`<Id>1000</Id>`

`<name>LCD Television HD Black 42 inches</name>`

`<Unit>ea</Unit>`

`<Cost>2000.00</Cost>`

`<description>Simple SKU</description>`

`<barcode></barcode>`

`</Item>`

`<Item>`

`<Id>1001</Id>`

`<name>LCD Television Model 01</name>`

`<Unit>ea</Unit>`

`<Cost>4015.00</Cost>`

`<description></description>`

`<barcode></barcode>`

`</Item>`

`<Item>`

`<Id>1003</Id>`

`<name>Plasma Television Model 01</name>`

`<Unit>ea</Unit>`

`<Cost>4020.00</Cost>`

`<description></description>`

`<barcode></barcode>`

`</Item>`

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem just use .equals("that string ")

Example

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
                    for( i=0; i < xmlelements.length;i++){


                        if (!soapObjMenu.getProperty(xmlelements[i]).toString().equals("anyType{}")){ // use when tag is empty...
               map.put(xmlelements[i], (soapObjMenu.getProperty(xmlelements[i]).toString()));}else{ map.put(xmlelements[i], (" "));}
                            }
                    Tags.add(map);
                                }}}
```

p.s. if you won't use space  in string it becomes problem then you send it to service from your app in this map.put(xmlelements[i], (" ")) so must change it just for space ;)

Nobody helped but i hope it helps for somebody ;)